# Profiler not loading data in Google App Engine in Java11

Tags: google-app-engine, java-11, profiler

For those looking for a solution, this is the entry in appengine-web.xml to enable profiling in Java11+:

```
<env-variables>
    <env-var name="JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" value="-agentpath:/opt/cprof/profiler_java_agent.so=-logtostderr,-cprof_enable_heap_sampling=true" />
</env-variables>
```

Here are additional helpful links:

Enable Profiler:
https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-java#standard-environment

View Profiler:
https://console.cloud.google.com/profiler

Cloud Profiler API
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudprofiler.googleapis.com/metrics?project=myproject

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @Craig D

> For those looking for a solution, this is the entry in appengine-web.xml to enable profiling in Java11+:

```
<env-variables>
    <env-var name="JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS" value="-agentpath:/opt/cprof/profiler_java_agent.so=-logtostderr,-cprof_enable_heap_sampling=true" />
</env-variables>
```

> Here are additional helpful links:
>
> Enable Profiler:
> https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-java#standard-environment
>
> View Profiler: https://console.cloud.google.com/profiler
>
> Cloud Profiler API https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudprofiler.googleapis.com/metrics?project=myproject

---

Additional reference:

[Cloud Profiler Java Agent](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-java)